# starting python3 from erlport

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'm using erlport, but it wants to start python 2.7 each time. In my system `python` is 2.7, and `python3` is 3.7

If I start `:python.start()`  like this `{:ok, pid} = :python.start(python: "/usr/local/bin/python3")` (which I got from `which python3`). I get this error `{:error, {:invalid_option, {:python, "/usr/local/bin/python3"}}}`

How can I start python3 instead of python2?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a double vs single quote issue.

```
:python.start(python: '/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7')
```